# Why should we use Binding and Dependency Property?

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a usercontrol design that includes a Button.
And I use it somewhere else and some Content has to be filled in there.
Now my question is that when I update this usercontrol I have access to its Content and I can fill it out.
The question is, should I use Binding for that? Why?

```
 <Grid   Margin="2,5,2,5">
    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Button x:Name="button" Margin="2, 4, 2, 4"
                Content="{Binding content}" 
                Click="button_Click" 
                Background="Transparent" 
                Foreground="Black"
                Height="23"
                FontSize="10"
                Cursor="Hand" Padding="1"
                BorderThickness="0" MouseEnter="button_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="button_MouseLeave"></Button>
    </Border>
</Grid>



public string content 
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(contentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(contentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty contentProperty =
               DependencyProperty.Register("content", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonView), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

Comment: This does not make sense. There is already a Content dependendy property in Button (or more accurately its base class ContentControl), so why would you define a new one? What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Now I have to take the button after defining the control elsewhere, then fill in the content.

Comment: var buttonRespose = new ButtonView()
                        {
                            content = button.title,      
                        };

Comment: buttonRespose.button.Content = button.title;